# not giving output the way I’m expecting

Tags: python, loops, range

> Print the following pattern. There is exactly one space between any two consecutive numbers on any line. There are no spaces at the end of any line.
>
> ```
> 1 2 1
> 1 2 3 2 1
> 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
> 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
> ```

this was the question

```
for i in range(1, 6):
# Print numbers in increasing order
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        print(j, end=' ')

# Print numbers in decreasing order
    for j in range(i - 1, 0, -1):
        print(j, end=' ')

# Move to the next line
    print()
```

when we print the above code I’m getting

```
1 
1 2 1 
1 2 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: So you have one unexpected extra line at the start of the output, and otherwise your output is identical to the expected. Each line is produced by one iteration of the `for i` loop... it sounds like you need to do one iteration less.

Comment: Start your range at 2 rather than 1?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this is not a question. Please read [ask]. See also [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). If you want to ask for help with your code, what do you need help with exactly? Like, what have you tried to fix the problem yourself, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct code should be:

```
for i in range(2, 6):
    for j in range(1,  i + 1):
        print(j, end=' ')
    for j in range(i - 1, 0, -1):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```

The first loop will be 4 times, every time should begin with 1, so the range of the second loop starts with 1.